# My Connection with HSQL Database over the Eclipse HSQL Database Manager does not work

Tags: java, sql, database, eclipse, hsqldb

I want to connect my hsql databse with the eclipse hsql database managger into with my eclipse and I think the code is pretty right but it gives me this error:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.createStatement()" because "this.con" is null
at peraLinq.Main.selectAll(Main.java:36)
at peraLinq.Main.main(Main.java:30)**

How can I fix it?

```
package peraLinq;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {
    Connection con = null;
    public Main() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.hasqldb.jdbcDriver");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            return;
        }
        
        con = null;
        
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hasqldb:file:C:\\Users\\usera\\Desktop\\peraLinq\\database\\saves; shutdown=true", "root", "root");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.selectAll();

    }
    
    public void selectAll() {
        try {   
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers";
        
        
            ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while(res.next()) {
                String id = res.getString(1);
                String name = res.getString(2);
                String email = res.getString(3);
                System.out.println(id + " " + name + " " + email);
            }
            res.close();
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does that JDB URL look right? `jdbc:hasqldb`

should that be `jdbc:hsqldb`?

It seems likely that `Class.forName("org.hasqldb.jdbcDriver");` is failing as the jdbc driver name is wrong. If this fails, the method just returns, leaving `con` still equal to `null`.

Correct the name of the jdbc driver in the `Class.forName` statement, and try it again.

It's probably worth putting `e.printStackTrace()` in all your `catch` blocks too - it'll be easier to work out what's going wrong.

Comment: What could it be else?

Comment: What else? Correct the spelling in the URL `getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\\Users\\u...`